# Kafka Conect JDBC Postgres - Can i write entire json to one column without parsing values to columns?

Tags: json, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Can i write entire json to one column using Confluent Kafka JDBC connector in format?

---

```
 Key|Value
  1 | {....}
  2 | {....}
  3 | {....}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with Postgres, and only if you predefine the table

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/46#issuecomment-1135209669

Otherwise, Mongo/DocumentDB might be better for JSON data than a relational database

Comment: And only with Avro? :)

Comment: A structured payload. So Jsonschema, Protobuf, or Avro should all be possible. I've not personally tried with anything else, but transforms can be used with plain json records create a structured record

Comment: Confirmed, its working also with jsonschema, i've also tested it with glue schema registry and it's working :) Thanks a lot